# Mail Merge Script with inputbox

Tags: google-apps-script, mailmerge

I am trying to change one word from a template I have in a spreadsheet, for the value that the user inputs through the inputbox. When I run my script it doesnt change the word, any ideas??

```
function sendEmails() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var time = Browser.inputBox("Enter TIME");
var address = "albdominguez25@gmail.com";
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Templates"));
var emailTemplate = ss.getRange("B1").getValue();
//here I am trying to replace the word "TIME" on my template to the value entered on             the inputBox
emailTemplate.replace("TIME",time);
var emailSubject = "Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge";    

MailApp.sendEmail(address, emailSubject, emailTemplate);
```

}

Comment: As shown in the answer and as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) : The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

Read more about regular expressions in our RegExp Tutorial and our RegExp Object Reference.

**This method does not change the original string.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Albert,

I believe the source of your replace is not assigning the result of the emailTemplate.replace to a variable.

I also did a little bit to the SpreadsheetApp call.  Depends on what you are after of course.

Jim

```
function sendEmails() {
  var emailTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange("B1").getValue();
  var time = Browser.inputBox("Enter TIME");
  var address = "jcampbell@neonova.net";
  emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace("TIME",time);
  var emailSubject = "Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge";    

  MailApp.sendEmail(address, emailSubject, emailTemplate);
}
```

Comment: Jim!! Thank you so much, I have been struggling with this for a couple of days already, but your example is finally working as I wanted. I truly appreciated it.                                                           Albert